# MySQL query to find girls living in same state

Tags: mysql, sql

**Que -Find out the female students who belongs to same state.**
[image: STUDENTS TABLE]

```
SELECT (A.NAME),B.NAME,A.STATE,B.STATE,A.GENDER,B.GENDER.
FROM STUDENT A
JOIN STUDENT B 
ON (A.STATE = B.STATE)AND A.NAME!=B.NAME AND (A.GENDER=B.GENDER) AND A.GENDER ="F";
```

As per the above query if person A and B satisfy the condition ,B and A also satisfy ,in such cases , there are two tuples  A-B and B-A ,which are actually not needed ,since A-B is sufficient .

****what modifications do you need to make ?****

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the non equality check on the name to an *inequality*:

```sql
SELECT A.NAME, B.NAME, A.STATE, B.STATE, A.GENDER, B.GENDER.
FROM STUDENT A
INNER JOIN STUDENT B 
    ON A.STATE = B.STATE AND
       A.NAME < B.NAME AND
       A.GENDER = b.GENDER AND
WHERE
    A.GENDER = 'F';
```

To be clear, the criterion `A.NAME < B.NAME` will ensure that each pair of student matches will only include the lexicographically smaller name followed by the larger one.